# Trying to use fetch with hooks on a react native project. Error => Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React Child

Tags: json, api, react-native, react-hooks

how are you?

I am a newbie trying my best here to develop a simple app where I must use an API to fetch some data about one country. 
I am currently trying to figure out how to do this in react native with the use of hooks and the fetch method. 
The API I am using: https://restcountries.eu/

Here's the sample code:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import { Text, StyleSheet, View, ActivityIndicator,FlatList } from 'react-native';


const MainInfoScreen = () => {

  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [data, setData] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/callingcode/82')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => setData(json))
      .catch((error) => console.error(error))
      .finally(() => setLoading(false));
  });

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 24 }}>
      {isLoading ? <ActivityIndicator/> : (
        <FlatList
          data={data}
          keyExtractor={({ id }, index) => id}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <Text>{item}</Text>
          )}
        />
      )}
    </View>
  );
};


const styles = StyleSheet.create({});

export default MainInfoScreen;
```

And here's the error:

```
Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {name, topLevelDomain, alpha2Code, alpha3Code, callingCodes, capital, altSpellings, region, subregion, population, latlng, demonym, area, gini, timezones, borders, nativeName, numericCode, currencies, languages, translations, flag, regionalBlocs, cioc}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

To be honest the whole point isn't even trying to list the data in a FlatList, I only wanted to fetch some specific data and place them in variables for using in my application as a means to show i can fetch this from an API. 
The ListItem component is only being used as I have tried following another tutorial that worked perfectly with one API, but not the one im using for some reason.

I believe the main reason is that i need to map this data as I believe I may be working with an Array, but again, im not too sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warning message is giving you a clue. You can't render an object as a React child. But you can use [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to visualize the object, this way you can figure out what and how you want to render the information contained in that object.

The example below is written in plain React (Stackoverflow cannot render native code). But the functionality is the same. `<div>` would be the equivalent of `<View>`.

```js
function App() {
  
  const [ data, setData ] = React.useState(null)
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/callingcode/82')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => setData(json))
      .catch((error) => console.error(error))
  }, [])


  return (
    <div>
      {JSON.stringify(data)}
    </div>
  )
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

So, in your code you would write:

```
<View>
  <Text>{JSON.stringify(data)}</Text>
</View>
```

Comment: Dear Juan, 

Did anyone tell you today that you are blessing? Cause you are! 

Thanks very much. I really appreciate this help!

Comment: Happy to help @BrandonBoyd